# Multiple versions of jQuery with Callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using 2 versions of jQuery (CMS requires 1.4, I need 1.9 for flot / graphing). I have it setup like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQueryOriginal = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
 //Other libraries...

<script type="text/javascript">
   //Save the new jQuery.  
   var jq = jQuery.noConflict( true );
   //Restore the original one.
   jQuery = jQueryOriginal;  
   $ = jQuery;
</script>
```

The problem I am having is in my code I make a callback to do the actual graphing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[id=startDate]').datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2012, 4 - 1, 30), maxDate: -7, dateFormat: 'yy-m-d' });  
        $('input[id=endDate]').datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2012, 4 - 1, 30), maxDate: -7, dateFormat: 'yy-m-d' });  
        // Default to 7 days ago
        var date = new Date(Date.now() - (7*24*60*60*1000)); 
        loadData($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-m-d', date),
            $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-m-d', date), 'plotData');
        })
    })(jq);

    function loadData(start, end, callback) {
        jq("#startDateLabel").text(start);
        jq("#endDateLabel").text(end);
        var URLString="/getJSONData.php?start="+start+"&end="+end+"&callback=?";
        jq.ajax({
            url: URLString,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: callback,
            cache: true,
            success: function(json) {}
       });
    }

    function updateGraph() {
        loadData(jq('input[id=startDate]').val(),jq('input[id=endDate]').val(), 'plotData');
    }
</script>
```

How do I do this so that the function in the callback (`plotData`) can use my named jQuery variable `jq`?

Plotdata looks like this:

```
function plotData(data) {
    var power = [];
    var energy = [];
    var totalEnergy = 0;
    var date = new Date();

    for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            date = parseInt(data[i].Time) * 1000; 
            totalEnergy = totalEnergy + parseFloat(data[i].Energy);
            power.push([ date, data[i].Power / 1000 ]);
            energy.push([ date, totalEnergy / 1000 ]);
    }

 .... //Snip 
    var plot = $.plot($("#container"), [ {
            label : "kWh",
            data : energy,
            color : "rgb(0, 99, 255)",
            yaxis : 2,
            lines : {
                    fill : true
            }
    }, {
            label : "kW",
            data : power,
            color : "rgb(215, 89, 39)",
            yaxis : 1
    } ], options);

}
```

Comment: Which function do you need to use the jq object? loadData or updateGraph?

Comment: @RobM. In `plotData` - function is not shown, but is part of a library I add.

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing any of the content of `plotData`. Without knowing, I would probably just add a parameter for the jq object and modify your `plotData` function to use that

Comment: Just saying, I hate working with multiple jQuery versions.  What a headache!

Comment: @RobM. I can post some of plotData, I had not expected the contents of the callback function to be relevant other than the are referencing jQuery through `$`.

Comment: That was the only part I was curious about

Comment: Are there cases when `plotData` uses the other version of jQuery (non `jq`)? Seems like you could just alter the function to use `jq` or put `var $ = jq;` at the top of your function if not.

Comment: @RobM. Ok - that did work. there are 4 libraries and I modified them all this way and it is functioning (some I added the `var $ = jq`, others I just switched the `jQuery` references to `jq`. Was hoping for a solution which would allow me to no mod the js files, but happy to be working at all at this point. Post as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest altering your function by assigning `jq` to `$` at the top of the function body, or pass the jq object as a parameter:

```
function plotData(args){
     var $ = jq;
}
```

OR

```
function plotData(args, $){

}

plotData(...., jq);
```

Comment: For posterity: did the first in the plotdata function. in other libraries also altered to reference the jq variable specifically. needed to ensure these libraries were loaded after the `jq` var was created.